# How to speed up processing/writing of one complex dataset

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have one function which goes throw large amount of data (billions rows) and returns tuple

> Dataset[ (Seq[Data1], Seq[Data2], Seq[Data3]) ]

This result dataset contains even larger number of rows (compare to input)

```
val result: Dataset[ (Seq[Data1], Seq[Data2], Seq[Data3]) ] = process(file, spark)

Seq[Data1] = billions rows
Seq[Data2] = millions rows
Seq[Data3] = millions rows (less than Data2)
```

Now I need to write these 3 sequences into separate avro files.

How to do it in effective way?

Currently I use flatmap function to separate these Seqs :

```
result.flatMap( row => row._1).write.mode(SaveMode.Append).avro(path1) //Data1
 result.flatMap( row => row._2).write.mode(SaveMode.Append).avro(path2) //Data2
 result.flatMap( row => row._3).write.mode(SaveMode.Append).avro(path3) //Data3
```

From processing times I see that all 3 calls of flatMap and writing avro file took same time.
So it looks like process function has been called 3times (per each flatmap)

How to call process function only once and then only filter results?

Is it possible to use caching?   (dataset contains billions of rows)

> result.cache()

What do you recommend to do?

Note: I use Spark version 2.2, scala 2.11.8

Answer (score 0):

You can try cache the result,and if there exists enough memory the result will cached,otherwise the caching will fail and the result will be recomputation.

Comment: what about to ds.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY) ?
I tried that, but no significant improvement so far

Comment: ds.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY) will cache the ds in disk.If the ds is large,then read the ds from disk will spend a lot of time.